# l3backend-xetex.def error when compiling latex

Tags: xetex

I am currently unable to compile anything and I get a number of errors surrounding l3backend-xetex.def.

I am trying to compile my MWE:

```
 \documentclass{report}

 \begin{document}
    
hello world

 \end{document}
```

and I am getting these errors:

[image]

I am using TeXstudio 2.12.22 and compiling with XeLaTeX

Any help to solve these errors would be appreciated!

Comment: Perhaps you have unmatched versions of `latex2e` and `l3backend` installed. Upgrade them to the latest versions may help. If the problem remains, find their exact versions in log file and paste them here.

Comment: Don't show only the summary of your editor. Show the full log-file until the first error.